# How can I extend bytes csv coverage on my python script

Tags: python, google-api, gspread

When I input 1 or 10000 **csvContents = csv_file.read(10000)** it limits the data on csv that transfer to spreadsheet, my goal is to capture all columns and rows, can someone help me what I need to modify with my script to capture entire csv file?.

```
def extract_csv(csv, sheet_id):
    with open(csv, 'r') as csv_file:
        csvContents = csv_file.read(1)

    body = {
        'requests': [{
            'pasteData': {
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "rowIndex": "0",
                    "columnIndex": "0",
                },
                "data": csvContents,
                "type": 'PASTE_NORMAL',
                "delimiter": ',',
            }
        }]
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) library.

```py
import csv

def extract_csv(csv, sheet_id):
    with open('eggs.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Hi, I already figured it out what I need to add on my script

I added import csv and encoding.

Thank you for you inputs! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [import_csv](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html#gspread.Client.import_csv).

This method will import the entire content of the CSV file and create a new sheet with the content.

See documentation for details it contains a example.

**Warning**: read the side note, this method will remove all sheets from your spreadsheet then replace the first sheet with the content of the CSV file